# Difference between cin and cin.get

Tags: c++, prompt, cin

I am wondering why my code works. There are two `std::cin` , but the second one doesn´t open a new line in the terminal for my input (isn´t `std::cin` supposed to do that?). I thought that `std::cin.get` is used for getting information out of a string.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char ch;
    std::cin >> ch;
    switch(ch) {
        case '.':
        case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
        case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
            std::cin.putback(ch);
            double value;
            std::cin >> value;
            std::cout << value << "\n";
        default:
            return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to extract the first value out of my input (e.g. "12.4 + 5") and it works (value = 12.4), but why? Where is the second prompt?

Comment: The first `std::cin >> ch` only reads one char, so there is much more left in the buffer to read more input. Especially if you put that char back and start over!

Comment: You can do the following: `int i; cin >> i;` but you can't do `cin.get(i);`

Comment: IMHO, you should enter the number as a string.  You can then test whether the number is valid or not; then there are many methods for converting the string to a number.

Comment: `cin` itself is not responsible for prompting the user. The user's terminal handles that, and then sends the input to your app. `cin` receives that input and puts into a memory buffer. You are reading a `char` from that buffer and then putting it back into the buffer. The terminal is not involved in that action, hence why there is no need for a 2nd prompt.

Comment: You are asking about `std::cin.get` but you never use it in your code.

Comment: Ignoring the overloads that work with `basic_streambuf` objects, there are only two things you can read using `std::cin.get`: 1. a single character (as either an `int` or `char`), or 2. a C-string (i.e., array of `char`, with a null character (`'\0'`) added after the characters that were read). See [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get).